# How to set an app's UIWindow color when calling it from ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiwindow

In the App delegate, it is possible to set an app's `UIWindow` color as seen in the code.

However, when trying to set an app's `UIWindow` color to a different color in the `ViewController`, a call for example to `self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()` gets ignored. No errors occur, but no color change occurs either.

Question:

1 - How can I set an app's window color when calling it in the `ViewController`?
Note: I'm not trying to change a View background color, but the `UIWindow` color which sits behind a View.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        return true

    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try accessing the window through your `AppDelegate` or `UIApplication` classes:

```
if let window = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window)! as UIWindow! {
    window.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
}
```

or

```
if let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first as UIWindow! {
    window.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
}
```

Comment: `UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()` He will need also to set `view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()`

Comment: Many thanks. With a slight change to option one, it worked, so did option two. Any chance you could explain the difference between the two options, and why it needs to be encased in an if statement to work? Thanks.

Comment: @user4806509 the `if` is just to make the code a little cleaner, you can do this in a single line like Leo Dabus commented.  The difference here is we're taking the reference your AppDelegate has to the `window` vs the array of UIWindows associated with your UIApplication class (your application can have more than one window).  Your initial `self.window` attempt didn't work because it's possible that your view controller did not have a reference to it's window at that time (it wasn't presented, etc).

Comment: JAL , @LeoDabus I have a new question related to `UIWindow` color at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993514

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5:**

```
if let window = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window as? UIWindow {
    window.backgroundColor = .red
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Objective-C you can use this code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // your code
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor yourColor]; 

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

In your SceneDelgate:

```
var window: UIWindow?


func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

     // Add UIWindowScene Background color
    self.window?.backgroundColor = .red
}
```