# Changing UIWindow image (backgroundColor using a UIColor patternImage) with an animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uicolor, uiwindow

I am trying to transition with an animation between two `UIWindow` images (set using `backgroundColor` with a `UIColor` `patternImage`).

I have two images `myImage1` and `myImage2`. I change the `UIWindow` `backgroundColor` once using the function `changeImage1()` and then again using the function `changeImage2()`. I also set the `view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()` so that I can see what is happening on the `UIWindow`. Code below.

**Test A :**

When I change `window.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()` to `window.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()`, I get a nice transition on the `UIWindow` between the colors animating red to blue. (See Code A.)

**Test B:**

However when I set a pattern image `window.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage:...)` and call `changeImage1()`, `myImage1` animates nicely, however when I then call `changeImage2()` there is no animation,  `myImage2` abruptly replaces `myImage1`. (See Code B.)

**Questions:**

*1 - How can I transition with an animation on UIWindow between `myImage1` and `myImage2`?*

*2 - What am I missing in my code that simply swaps the images instead of animate between them, why is `myImage1` animating but `myImage2` is not?*

*3 - Are there other ways to animate two images/cross dissolve on `UIWindow` that don't use UIColor(patternImage:...)?*

**Code:**

A:

```
func changeImage1() {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()  //show UIWindow

    UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
        if let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first as UIWindow! {
            window.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor() //Animation OK
        }
        }, completion: nil)
    }

func changeImage2() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
        if let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first as UIWindow! {
            window.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor() //Animation OK
        }
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

B:

```
func changeImage1() {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()  //show UIWindow

    UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
        if let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first as UIWindow! {
            window.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "myImage1")!) //Animation OK
        }
        }, completion: nil)
    }

func changeImage2() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
        if let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first as UIWindow! {
            window.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "myImage2")!) //NO animation
        }
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: In general, an iOS app has just one UIWindow and it is unseen, unaffected, and unchanging. Why are you doing this at all? It is your root view controller that the user sees at the back of everything; that's the place to do an animation.

Comment: @matt It can be changed and be seen under certain circumstances which is why I'm attempting to make changes to it.

Comment: @matt Not entirely true. Most iOS apps have at least 3 windows - 1 being used to display status bar and 1 being used to display keyboard (system windows). There are also various use cases when creating a new window (usually only temporarily) makes sense.  However, you are right that animating a change from window to window is impossible. Animations have to be always done to views inside one window, e.g. changing `alpha` of a view.

Answer (score 1):

Animation implies the existence of a series of intermediate states. There is no intelligible notion of an intermediate state between two pattern images; hence, that animation (from one pattern image to another) fails.

A workaround might be to animate to a color and then, in its completion handler, from the color to the next pattern image. But even that might fail; actually, I'm surprised to hear that your animation from a color to a pattern image worked in the first place.

Comment: `window.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage` works the first time, changing from i guess no image to the pattern image. I didn't expect that `UIColor patterncolor` would be handled much differently than `UIColor`. Are there other ways to animate two images/cross dissolve on `UIWindow` that don't use pattern images?

Comment: As I said in my comment, I'm not sympathetic to doing _anything_ the UIWindow, as the user should never even see it. But sure, obviously you could just have an image view in the background and dissolve between one image view (holding one pattern color) and another (holding the other pattern color).

Comment: Users can see it `UIWindow` in a segue for example. Can you explain more about the image view in the background of a UIWindow and dissolving between one image view (holding one pattern color) and another? If possible showing what that might look like in code?

Comment: It's the same as any basic dissolve. You have an image view showing. You make another image view with alpha zero and place it where the image view already is. You animate changing its alpha to 1 and the original's alpha to 0. In the completion handler you remove the old image view.

Comment: Or call `transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:`, but the effect will be exactly the same as what I just described.