# How to change UIWindow background color through a view controller

Tags: ios, swift

This question is really similar to this: [How to set an app's UIWindow color when calling it from ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35920020/how-to-set-an-apps-uiwindow-color-when-calling-it-from-viewcontroller). However, the solutions there aren't working.

Ever since apple changed the window to be located in the scene delegate (instead of the app delegate) I haven't been able to change the window (UIWindow) background color outside of scene delegate (using the methods in the article above). Is there any way to either call a function inside of Scene Delegate (through a view controller) or to change the window background color in a view controller. The reason I need this feature is because I handle my themes inside of the app, and when the user changes the theme I need the UIWindow background color to also change (for all of my app) for any cases where the UIWindow color shows (ex: presenting a view controller). A solution which I've tried is:

```
if let window = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window as? UIWindow {
    window.backgroundColor = .red
}
```

But it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set an app's UIWindow color when calling it from ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35920020/how-to-set-an-apps-uiwindow-color-when-calling-it-from-viewcontroller)

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't work for me. That's the reason I asked the question. The answer I accepted ended up working though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it in any `controller` like this

```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
          view.window?.backgroundColor = .red
    }
```

[image]

Comment: @LeoDabus its for iOS ?

Comment: your comment disappears :/

Comment: As simple as this is, thank you so much for this. I couldn't find it anywhere else for some reason.

Comment: yeah its pretty simple .. glad to help you on this. .. happy coding =)