# didFinishLaunchingWithOptions Crashing on window background change

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my code.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // your code

    NSLog(@"applicationDidFinishLaunching");
 
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
 
    return YES;
}
```

It keeps crashing showing this error. Can't understand why. Any help appreciated.

```
    -[AppDelegate setWindow:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000068530
    2021-10-08 19:59:39.790392+0300 sidebar_test[1570:61543] 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate setWindow:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000068530'
```

Comment: Have you a window object set in your app delegate ?

Comment: @property (nonatomic,strong) UIWindow *window;

Comment: Where is it set ?

Comment: I haven't set, now i have you are right. The strange thing is that self.window did not return any errors so i thought that i shouldn't add a window property! By the way now the background colour does not change!

Comment: I use     self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions but no change of colour occurs.

Comment: I do not not if is still like this but you need to make the window visible : [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; then you need to add subviews …

Comment: Nope didn't work but thanks for the clarification. I do not understand why they are making it so hard when we could have done it through the storyboard if they give us an option!

Comment: I think you can create the window in storyboard and link it to @IBOutlet in your program. In this case you can setup the color in your storyboard.

Comment: The makekeyandvisible was present in Apple template projects.

Comment: There was a scenedelegate .h .m and the window was initialized there but could not make it work. I get a black screen! Thank you apple! :)

Comment: I find a post which may help you : [set app uiwindow color when calling from view controller ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35920020/how-to-set-an-apps-uiwindow-color-when-calling-it-from-viewcontroller). There have been a change in last versions of iOS with using windows array instead window property which is now deprecated.

Comment: window is now part of scenes despite technically you can still have one assigned to Appdelegate. So before setting the color of a window, check if that window exists. that way it might still work when window is instanciated from storyboard